# Question on linear span of subsets of $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ = $\Bbb{R}^3$. Consider

$S_1$ = {($x,y,z$)|$x^2$ + $y^2$ + $z^2$ = $1$} and

$S_2$ = {($x,y,z$)|$z$ = $0$}. Then choose the correct

1. $L$($S_1$ $\cup$ $S_2$) = $V$
2. $L$($S_1$) is a subspace of $L$($S_2$)
3. dim($L$($S_1$ $\cap$ $S_2$) = $2$
4. $L$($S_1$) $\cap$ $L$($S_2$) = $L$($S_1$ $\cap$ $S_2$)

This has been my attempt.

Since $S_2$ is a subspace therefore $L$($S_2$) is $S_2$ only.

Since ($0,0,0$) does not belong to $S_1$ therefore it is not a subspace.

Now $L$($S_1$) contains $3$ linearly independent vectors therefore its dimension is $3$ and hence its linear span is $V$.

Now as $S_2$ is two dimensional therefore $2$nd option is incorrect.

How to check the remaining options?

Comment: Presumably $L(X)$ denotes the span of $X$.

Comment: Use `\{` `\}` for braces within MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_1$ is the sphere of radius 1 centred at 0, $S_2$ is the $xy$ plane. $Int =S1 \cap S_2$ is the unit circle centred at $0$ on the $xy$ plane. $L(Int)$ is the whole $xy$ plane as it contains both the standard basis for the plane, and so is the span of $S_2$. $L(S_1)$ is whole space by the same logic and so is span of $S_1 \cup S_2$ . $L(S1) \cap L(S2)$ is also the $xy$ plane, by using the above logics. So only option 2 is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate $S_1\cap S_2$ (that's a circle in the $(x,y)$ coordinate plane $S_2$), and conclude as for the first cases.